# Comment Forms - place label inside the inputs

Tags: 7, forms, comments

I'm theming a comments section on a page in a D7 site.
What I want is for the label for the forms items to show as a `placeholder` attribute rather than above the element.

I've used a `hook_form_alter` to add the placeholder attributes, e.g.

```
$form['comment_body']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Add comment here');
```

…but don't seem to be able to hide the label. In a normal form I can set the label to hidden but there's no option under 'manage display' for the comment form.

Is there something I can do in my hook to do it instead? I know I can hide it with CSS but would like to know The Drupal Way™

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, answered my own question with a bit of help from the Form API Docs!! https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7

`'#title_display' => 'invisible'`

was what I needed!